Proof of Generalization of De Morgan's Law by induction
I'm working my way through the book Mathematical Logic by Chiswell&Hodges.
The chapter about Substitution introduced

the Substitution Theorem (if two formulas are logically equivalent and we apply the same substitution to both, the resulting formulas are also logically equivalent);
the Replacement Theorem (if we apply two logically equivalent substitutions to a formula, the resulting formulas are also logically equivalent).

Exercises 3.7.2b is asking me to prove a generalized De Morgan's Law:
Show the following generalized De Morgan Law, by induction on $n$:
If $\phi_{1},\phi_{2},\dots,\phi_{n}$ are any formulas then
$$
(\neg(\cdots(\phi_{1}\land \phi_{2})\land\dots)\land \phi_{n}))\quad eq \quad (\cdots((\neg \phi_{1})\lor(\neg \phi_{2}))\lor\dots)\lor(\neg \phi_{n}))
$$
The following is my attempt at a proof using both the Substitution and Replacement Theorem:
Base case: Let $n=2$. Then it is trivial to check by truth tables that
$$
(\neg(\phi_{1}\land \phi_{2}))\quad eq \quad ((\neg \phi_{1})\lor(\neg \phi_{2}))
$$
Inductive step: Suppose that if $\phi_{1},\phi_{2},\dots,\phi_{n}$ are any formulas then
$$
(\neg(\cdots(\phi_{1}\land \phi_{2})\land\dots)\land \phi_{n}))\quad eq \quad (\cdots((\neg \phi_{1})\lor(\neg \phi_{2}))\lor\dots)\lor(\neg \phi_{n}))
$$
We have to prove that
$$
(\neg((\cdots(\phi_{1}\land \phi_{2})\land\dots)\land \phi_{n})\land\phi_{n+1}))\quad eq \quad ((\cdots((\neg \phi_{1})\lor(\neg \phi_{2}))\lor\dots)\lor(\neg \phi_{n}))\lor(\neg \phi_{n+1}))
$$
Let $S$ be the substitution
$$
(\cdots(\phi_{1}\land \phi_{2})\land\dots)\land \phi_{n})/\phi_{1}, \phi_{n+1}/\phi_{2}
$$
Applying it to our base case we get
$$
(\neg((\cdots(\phi_{1}\land \phi_{2})\land\dots)\land \phi_{n})\land \phi_{n+1}))\quad eq \quad ((\neg(\cdots(\phi_{1}\land \phi_{2})\land\dots)\land \phi_{n}))\lor(\neg\phi_{n+1}))
$$
Now consider the formula
$$
(\psi\lor(\neg\phi_{n+1}))
$$
Then
$$\begin{align}
((\neg(\cdots(\phi_{1}\land \phi_{2})\land\dots)\land \phi_{n}))\lor(\neg\phi_{n+1}))\quad & is \quad (\psi \lor(\neg \phi_{n+1}))[(\neg(\cdots(\phi_{1}\land \phi_{2})\land\dots)\land \phi_{n}))/\psi] \\
((\cdots((\neg \phi_{1})\lor(\neg \phi_{2}))\lor\dots)\lor(\neg \phi_{n}))\lor(\neg \phi_{n+1}))\quad & is\quad (\phi \lor(\neg \phi_{n+1}))[(\cdots((\neg \phi_{1})\lor(\neg \phi_{2}))\lor\dots)\lor(\neg \phi_{n}))/\psi
\end{align}
$$
The Replacement Theorem tells us that
$$
((\neg(\cdots(\phi_{1}\land \phi_{2})\land\dots)\land \phi_{n}))\lor(\neg\phi_{n+1}))\quad eq\quad ((\cdots((\neg \phi_{1})\lor(\neg \phi_{2}))\lor\dots)\lor(\neg \phi_{n}))\lor(\neg \phi_{n+1}))
$$
And since $eq$ is an equivalence relation, by transitivity we have
$$
(\neg((\cdots(\phi_{1}\land \phi_{2})\land\dots)\land \phi_{n})\land\phi_{n+1}))\quad eq \quad ((\cdots((\neg \phi_{1})\lor(\neg \phi_{2}))\lor\dots)\lor(\neg \phi_{n}))\lor(\neg \phi_{n+1}))
$$
as required.
Now, is the proof correct? I assumed the authors wanted me to use both theorems, but I'm not quite sure if the substitutions I made in the proof are allowed,

Base case: This is a bit nitpicky but appeal to truth tables might be a little sloppy. The truth tables you mention don't assign truth values to any propositional symbols. So, they aren't really the truth tables for the formulas. In other words, your truth tables treat $\phi_{1}$ and $\phi_{2}$ as propositional symbols. But they are arbitrary formulas. The rows of these truth tables don't display any $\sigma$-structures. Instead,  each row would represent infinitely many possible $\sigma$-structures. Each depends on the propositional symbols that occur in $\phi_{1}$ and $\phi_{2}$. Some might find this a bit too picky. But, there's another reason to avoid it. A proof for the base case that doesn't appeal to truth tables gives you an idea for how to prove the inductive case.
Inductive case: Your substitution isn't allowed because you're replacing arbitrary formulas with formulas. A substitution only replaces propositional symbols with formulas. Recall that a substitution is a function. It maps to formulas. But, its domain is a set of propositional symbols. So, your $S$ doesn't satisfy the definition of a substitution.
Note that the text gives De Morgan's laws for formulas containing propositional symbols. They're not stated for arbitrary formulas. So, for example, they tell us that $(\neg (p_{1}\wedge p_{2}))$ eq $((\neg p_{1})\vee (\neg p_{2}))$. But they don't tell us that $(\neg (\phi_{1}\wedge \phi_{2}))$ eq $((\neg \phi_{1})\vee (\neg \phi_{2}))$. Of course, the latter is true by De Morgan's Laws. But, that's what you need to show for your base case. This suggests that we should start with two formulas which contain propositional symbols. This allows us to apply one of De Morgan's laws. And, it gives you propositional symbols to replace. So, you can apply the Substitution Theorem. You won't need the Replacement Theorem.
So, try this:
Base Case: $n=2$.
Define two formulas which contains propositional symbols. Show that the negation of one is logically equivalent to the other by one of De Morgan's laws. That is, define $\phi$ and $\psi$ in terms of propositional symbols. Then apply one of De Morgan's laws to show that $\neg\phi$ eq $\psi$. Then, define a substitution, $S$, by $\phi_{i}/p_{i} $. Apply the substitution to $\neg\phi$ and $\psi$. By the Substitution Theorem, $\neg\phi [S]$ eq $\psi [S]$. With appropriate choices for $\phi$ and $\psi$, you've shown the base case.
Inductive Case: Suppose the result holds for $n$.
Apply the same argument with a different substitution. Choose a substitution that allows you to apply the inductive hypothesis. Then, apply transitivity of the equivalence relation.
I hope this helps. Let me know if you'd like me to write a proof.

Thank you so much for the answer!
I don't know why I got the Substitution wrong, the book made it very clear to understand.
I'd really appreciate if you could write a proof because I like the way you write, it's really easy to follow your reasoning

Glad it helped. I'll write it up now.

Proof:
(By induction on $n$)
Suppose $k\in\mathbb{N}$ where $k\leq n$.
Base Case: $k=2$.
Let $\phi = (p_{1}\wedge p_{2})$ and $\psi = ((\neg p_{1}) \vee (\neg p_{2}))$. Then $\neg\phi = (\neg (p_{1}\wedge p_{2}))$ eq $((\neg p_{1}) \vee (\neg p_{2})) = \psi$ by one of De Morgan's Laws. Let $S$ be the substitution $\phi_{i}/p_{i}$, $i\in\{1,2\}$. Then $\neg\phi [S]= (\neg (\phi_{1}\wedge \phi_{2}))$ and $\psi [S] = ((\neg\phi_{1})\vee (\neg\phi_{2}))$. By the Substitution Theorem, $\neg\phi[S]$ eq $\psi [S]$. That is,
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
(\neg (\phi_{1} \wedge \phi_{2})) \quad &\mathrm{eq} \quad ((\neg \phi_{1}) \vee (\neg \phi_{2})).
\end{split}
\end{equation}
Inductive Case: Suppose the result holds for $k\leq n$.
Now let $S$ be the substitution $(\cdots (\phi_{1}\wedge\phi_{2} )\wedge\cdots )\wedge\phi_{n})/p_{0}, \phi_{n+1}/p_{1}$. Then
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\neg\phi [S] &\text{ eq } \psi[S] \qquad\text{by the Substitution Theorem}.  
\end{split}
\end{equation}
That is,
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
(\neg ((\cdots (\phi_{1}\wedge\phi_{2} )\wedge\cdots )\wedge\phi_{k})\wedge \phi_{k+1})) &\text{ eq } ((\neg (\cdots (\phi_{1}\wedge\phi_{2} )\wedge\cdots )\wedge\phi_{k})) \vee (\neg \phi_{k+1})) \\
\end{split}
\end{equation}
By the inductive hypothesis,
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
((\neg (\cdots (\phi_{1}\wedge\phi_{2} )\wedge\cdots )\wedge\phi_{k})) \vee (\neg \phi_{k+1})) &\text{ eq } ((\cdots ((\neg\phi_{1})\vee (\neg\phi_{2}))\vee\cdots )\vee (\neg\phi_{k})) \vee (\neg \phi_{k+1})).
\end{split}
\end{equation}
Since eq is an equivalence relation on the set of all formulas of $LP(\sigma)$ for some signature $\sigma$, the result follows by transitivity.
(Note that by the other De Morgan Law, the same goes with $\wedge$ and $\vee$ the other way round.)
$\square$
Hopefully, I didn't mess up any bracketing.

Very clear proof. Thank you very much! Out of curiosity, have you read the book too?

You're welcome! Yes I have.

@G.Ajello Did you ever solve Exercise 3.7.5 and 3.7.6? I decided to write up solutions to the book for fun. I didn't solve those. I think I got close with 3.7.5.  For 3.7.6, I didn't know whether the notation ST meant function composition or concatenation. I doubt it's composition because you could just take S=T = the identity function on the signature. So, a proof of that would be trivial.

For 3.7.5 I used a proof by contradiction. I also solved 3.7.6 but I actually can't remember how I did it

For 3.7.6 I think the notation [ST] means concatenation.

@G.Ajello Thanks!
